# precedence climbing in haskell: parsec mutual recursion error

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec, mutual-recursion

I'm programming the precedence climbing algorithm in Haskell, but for a reason unknown to me, does not work. I think that Parsec state info is lost at some point, but I don't even know that is the source of the error:

```
module PrecedenceClimbing where

import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.Char

{-
Algorithm

compute_expr(min_prec):
  result = compute_atom()

  while cur token is a binary operator with precedence >= min_prec:
    prec, assoc = precedence and associativity of current token
    if assoc is left:
      next_min_prec = prec + 1
    else:
      next_min_prec = prec
    rhs = compute_expr(next_min_prec)
    result = compute operator(result, rhs)

  return result
-}

type Precedence = Int
data Associativity = LeftAssoc
                   | RightAssoc
                   deriving (Eq, Show)
data OperatorInfo = OPInfo Precedence Associativity (Int -> Int -> Int)

mkOperator :: Char -> OperatorInfo
mkOperator = \c -> case c of
                     '+' -> OPInfo 1 LeftAssoc  (+)
                     '-' -> OPInfo 1 LeftAssoc  (-)
                     '*' -> OPInfo 2 LeftAssoc  (*)
                     '/' -> OPInfo 2 LeftAssoc  div
                     '^' -> OPInfo 3 RightAssoc (^)

getPrecedence :: OperatorInfo -> Precedence
getPrecedence (OPInfo prec _ _) = prec

getAssoc :: OperatorInfo -> Associativity
getAssoc (OPInfo _ assoc _) = assoc

getFun :: OperatorInfo -> (Int -> Int -> Int)
getFun (OPInfo _ _ fun) = fun

number :: Parsec String () Int
number = do
  spaces
  fmap read $ many1 digit

operator :: Parsec String () OperatorInfo
operator = do
  spaces
  fmap mkOperator $ oneOf "+-*/^"

computeAtom = do
  spaces
  number

loop minPrec res = (do
  oper <- operator
  let prec = getPrecedence oper
  if prec >= minPrec
  then do
    let assoc = getAssoc oper
        next_min_prec = if assoc == LeftAssoc
                        then prec + 1
                        else prec
    rhs <- computeExpr(next_min_prec)
    loop minPrec $ getFun oper res rhs
  else return res) <|> (return res)

computeExpr :: Int -> Parsec String () Int
computeExpr minPrec = (do
  result <- computeAtom
  loop minPrec result) <|> (computeAtom)

getResult minPrec = parse (computeExpr minPrec) ""
```

My program for some reason is only processing the first operation or the first operand depending on the case, but does not go any further

GHCi session:

```
*PrecedenceClimbing> getResult 1 "46+10"
Right 56
*PrecedenceClimbing> getResult 1 "46+10+1"
Right 56
```

Comment: Please try to boil that down to a [MCVE] and give a proper description of the problems you get.

Comment: done @leftaroundabout, now is better explained and shortened.

Comment: Could you comment in the expected values for `getResult 1 "46+10"` and `getResult 1 "46+10+1"`?

Comment: @haoformayor exactly the integer value of the arithmetic expression, so 56 and 57 respectively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what's wrong with your code but I'll offer these comments:

*(1)* These statements are not equivalent:

```
Generic Imperative: rhs = compute_expr(next_min_prec)

Haskell:            rhs <- computeExpr(next_min_prec)
```

The imperative call to `compute_expr` will *always* return. The Haskell call may fail in which case the stuff following the call never happens.

*(2)* You are really working against Parsec's strengths by trying to parse tokens one at a time in sequence. To see the "Parsec way" of generically parsing expressions with operators of various precedences and associativities, have a look at:

- [`buildExpression`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.10/docs/Text-Parsec-Expr.html#v:buildExpressionParser)
- [Parsec and Expression Printing](http://www.mega-nerd.com/erikd/Blog/CodeHacking/Haskell/parsec_expression_parsing.html)

**Update**

I've posted a solution to http://lpaste.net/165651

Comment: I'm just trying this algorithm to work, but I've upvoted your answer because I think is helpful for my future work and for the readers of this question.